# SVG filter can't work on firefox However work fine on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, svg

I write a animation By scss + svg
I use Promise to contorl the animation

After I finish on chrome Evething look like perfectly
However When I run in firefox, This everything was disappear which elements set filter svg

I set this svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <filter id="gooey">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="step1"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="step1" mode="matrix" values="
                1 0 0 0 0
                0 1 0 0 0
                0 0 1 0 0  
                0 0 0 19 -9" result="step2" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Meanwile set filter on scss

```
filter: url(./baidu_beer.html#gooey);
```

this is test result on firefox

[image]

when I unfocus the filter attribute

then everything was ok

[image]

[image]

This was my layout

[image]

Comment: Please paste your code as **text**.

Comment: Anything could be going on.  Please post a working example. No one wants to debug screenshots of your code.  We need an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: Your filter is invalid, feComposite requires an input named goo but you don't have any previous step with an output called goo. Feel free to report this to Chrome's bugtracker.

Comment: It was solved with @ Robert Longson advisement thx everybody